# quick sort time and space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

Quick is the in place algorithm which does not use any auxiliary array. So why memory complexity of this O(nlog(n)) ?

Similarly I understand it's worst case time complexity is O(n^2) but not getting why average case time complexity is O(nlog(n)). Basically I am not sure what do we mean when we say average case complexity ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity

Comment: You are confusing **time** and **space** complexity. For a [comparison sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) the absolute best average time complexity is `O(n lg(n))`.

Comment: "So why time complexity of this O(nlog(n))" Not using auxiliary arrays has an effect on space complexity, not on time complexity.

Comment: I am struggling to follow the logic of your question. For example, what's the connection between the first sentence and the second?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<n;++i) for(j=0;j<n;++j) sum+=i*j` - what is the time complexity? space complexity?

Comment: Because every recursion Algorithm are at least `O(nlog(n))`

Comment: @Gatusko what on earth are you talking about?? That is complete and utter nonsense. See [the Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).

Comment: @BoristheSpider It was typo mistake in first line where I typed Time complexity instead of memory complexity . Corrected it

Comment: @BoristheSpider My Bad not every recursion algorithms... I was checking my book and courses and What I tried to remeber was that every sorting algorithm that use comparasion is at least  (nlog(n))

Comment: Write the equation for the average case of QuickSort and solve it. You will find it's 1.39NlogN

Answer (score 0):

To your second point an excerpt from Wikipedia:

*The most unbalanced partition occurs when the partitioning routine returns one of sublists of size n − 1. This may occur if the pivot happens to be the smallest or largest element in the list, or in some implementations (e.g., the Lomuto partition scheme as described above) when all the elements are equal.*

*If this happens repeatedly in every partition, then each recursive call processes a list of size one less than the previous list. Consequently, we can make n − 1 nested calls before we reach a list of size 1. This means that the call tree is a linear chain of n − 1 nested calls. The ith call does O(n − i) work to do the partition, and {\displaystyle \textstyle \sum _{i=0}^{n}(n-i)=O(n^{2})} , so in that case Quicksort takes O(n²) time.*

Because you usually don't know what exact numbers you have to sort and you don't know, which pivot element you choose, you have the chance, that your pivot element isn't the smallest or biggest number in the array you sort. If you have an array of **n** not duplicated numbers, you have the chance of (n - 2) / n, that you don't have a worst case.